# Can a process start executing with 0 Pages in main memory?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I am reading a Book on **Operating System (Galvin**). While explaining **Demand Paging** it says

In the extreme case, **we can start executing a process with no pages in
  memory**. When the operating system sets the instruction pointer to the first
  instruction of the process, which is on a non-memory-resident page, the process
  immediately faults for the page.

My question is how OS can set the instruction pointer for a process for which not even single page is in memory (because the address in instruction pointer cannot be a disc or secondary memory address, It has to be a main memory address but 0 pages means nothing is in memory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what virtual memory is. It means that there's an ephemeral mapping between logical addresses, which are known and constant, and physical addresses, which are transient. The normal level of processing then works purely in logical addresses, without necessarily having any knowledge of what's going on physically.

So the OS would e.g. say that the binary A is logically available at address N. It will then mark in the virtual map that the pages covering N to N+(size of binary) are currently faults. Having set the PC to N (or whatever the entry point is), the MMU will fire a fault as soon as the CPU tries to read from the PC. At that point the paging mechanism will catch the fault and do the usual things.

Comment: Great. Just for the sake of information, does that also implies that the process will be in Swap Space?

Comment: @AkashMahajan most OSs can directly map a file to a particular address range, with virtual-prompted reads (and writes, if relevant) going to and from that file rather than to and from swap. So probably the OS would just map the original executable file to that range, rather than copying from the binary into swap.